# How can I tell LINQ to construct my entities with my own query data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I know it will sound strange but please don't mind:

In C#, let's say I manually do with ADO or anything else:

```
SELECT * FROM Member
```

Then I want LINQ to construct my `Member` entities from the data I just retrieved myself from the query...

Do you have an idea if it's possible?

Thanks

Comment: C# 3.0 really does not have the functionality to create dynamic types.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Member class was previously generated by SqlMetal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, sorry:

Context::Translate(DbDataReader) - Converts an existing DbDataReader to objects.